# Products of sliding time windows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns "date" and "percentage_change".
I need the products of the percentage changes of different time windows.
For example time window = 2: The products of 2010 and 2011 (1.1 * 0.95) ; 2011 and 2012; ...; 2019 and 2020 . So for the time window=2 I will get 9 results.

For the time window = 3: The products of 2010,2011 and 2012 (1.1 * 0.95 * 1.3); 2011, 2012 and 2013; ...; 2018,2019 and 2020.  So for the time window=3 I will get 8 results.

For the time window = 9: The products of 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,...,2019 (1.1 * 0.95 * ... * 0.9); 2011,2012,2013, ...,2020 (0.95 * 1.3 * ... * 0.9).
So for the time window=9 I will get 2 results.

```
date        percentage_change
2010-01-01  1.1
2011-01-01  0.95
2013-01-01  1.3
2014-01-01  1.2
2015-01-01  1.1
2016-01-01  0.8
2017-01-01  0.6
2018-01-01  1.1
2019-01-01  1.7
2020-01-01  0.9
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.rolling(window=WINDOW_SIZE)` to set the window size then apply the multiplication.
Here is a sample code (I used your data to generate it):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'date': [
        '2010-01-01',  
'2011-01-01',
'2013-01-01',
'2014-01-01',
'2015-01-01',
'2016-01-01',
'2017-01-01',
'2018-01-01',
'2019-01-01',
'2020-01-01'
    ],
    'percentage_change': [
1.1,
0.95,
1.3,
1.2,
1.1,
0.8,
0.6,
1.1,
1.7,
0.9]
}

df = (
pd.DataFrame(data)
.rolling(3)
.apply(np.prod)
.fillna(0)
)
df.head(10)
```

It takes window size, then applies `np.prod`. the `fillna(0)` is because if we pick a window_size=3, the first two elements will have NaN values.
I hope this helps!